# How to repartition Mac HD when Disk Utility gives "Operation Failed" (to install Linux)

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning

I'm trying to repartition the 500 GB hard drive of my 13" MacBook Pro, so I can dual-boot it with Linux.

When I click the "+" in Disk Utility to split the 500 GB drive in 2 (I want a 100 GB partition for OS X and 400 GB for Linux), Disk Utility gives a "Operation Failed" error message.

[Operation Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqWt5.png)

I also tried to just shrink the 500 GB Mac partition to 100 GB but that gave the same "Operation Failed" error message.

I tried to format as FAT32 first and ext later but both failed.

Then I thought the problem was that my hard drive is encrypted (File Vault) so I unencrypted the hard drive but it still gives the "Operation Failed" message.

How to repartition the Mac hard drive another way because Disk Utility does noet work? Is there a command line utility for Mac that could do this?

Comment: Please provide the full disk layout ( imgur pic works), also what happens if you try the same from the 'live installer' of your chosen linux distro?